# Knockout custom format to attributes to more than one

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding

I took a custom binding from Freeman's Pro Javascript for WebApps which basically adds a prefix and/or suffix to an attribute

```
ko.bindingHandlers.formatAttr = {
    init: function(element, accessor) {
        $(element).attr(accessor().attr, composeString(accessor()));
    },
    update: function(element, accessor) {
        $(element).attr(accessor().attr, composeString(accessor()));
    }
};
```

Using this javascript function

```
function composeString(bindingConfig) {
    var result = bindingConfig.value;
    if (bindingConfig.prefix) {
        result = bindingConfig.prefix + result;
    }
    if (bindingConfig.suffix) {
        result += bindingConfig.suffix;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works fine as for example

```
<input data-bind="formatAttr: { attr: 'id', prefix: 'InterestedParty_', suffix: '__Id', value: $data.Guid }" type="hidden"/>
```

But how could I achieve to make it work for two different attributes in the same input? I've tried some things but either fails or just take the last one. I could create one custom one for each property but then I would lose the generality of it.

Thanks

Comment: You mean something like "formatAttr: { attr: ['id', 'name'], prefix: 'InterestedParty_', suffix: '__Id', value: $data.Guid }"? So the same prefix, suffix, value get applied to the `id` AND the `name` attribute?

Comment: Well, ideally I would like to be able to apply different prefixes and suffixes to each attribute.

Comment: I tried that but it only got the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your binding handler with the help of some jQuery to work also with arrays:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.formatAttr = {
    init: function(element, accessor) {
        var value = accessor();
        if (!$.isArray(value))
            value = [value]

        $.each(value, function(index, item){
            $(element).attr(item.attr, composeString(item));
        });

    },
    update: function(element, accessor) {
        var value = accessor();
        if (!$.isArray(value))
            value = [value]

       $.each(value, function(index, item){
            $(element).attr(item.attr, composeString(item));
       });
    }
};
```

So now you can pass an array of `{ attr, prefix, suffix, value }` object as a parameter to your binding:

```
<input data-bind="formatAttr: [
   { attr: 'id', prefix: 'InterestedParty_', suffix: '__Id', value: $data.Guid },
   { attr: 'name', prefix: 'Other_', suffix: '__Name', value: $data.Name }]"
   type="hidden" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WKZZ9/1/).